# Using LESS / CSS / Mixins and passing values from classes

Tags: css, less

I have this little snippet of css which i want to use transform and then add rotate into it but getting a failure... am i doing this wrong? Im new to LESS so sorry if im going about this wrong.

CSS:

```
.class {
    &::before {
        .transform(.rotate(@deg: 45deg));
    }
    &::after {
        .transform(.rotate(@deg: -45deg));
    }
}
```

MIXIN:

```
.transform(@string){
    -webkit-transform:  @string;
    -moz-transform:     @string;
    -ms-transform:      @string;
    -o-transform:       @string;
}

.rotate (@deg) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(@deg);
    -moz-transform:      rotate(@deg);
    -ms-transform:       rotate(@deg);
    -o-transform:        rotate(@deg);
}
```

Comment: Use autoprefixer instead.

Comment: Sorry, how do i do that? im really new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer or https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/

Comment: This is for a coding test for a job, so having to do myself so cant use plugins or anything like that mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the way you have things set up above, you're basically passing the entire rotate mixin into the transform mixin. Which, if it actually knew how to parse, would end up with pretty garbled code. Instead, you can just use the top mixin and pass rotate into it. This is a better route, because it would allow you to use multiple transforms (which is a pretty common usage). Here's an example:

```
.transform(@string){
  -webkit-transform:  @string;
  -moz-transform:     @string;
  -ms-transform:      @string;
  -o-transform:       @string;
}

.class {
  &::before {
    .transform(rotate(45deg));
  }
}
```

And if you wanted to call rotate and translate at a future time, it would be as easy as adding translate, as well.

```
.class {
  &::before {
    .transform(translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea that seems to get rid of the error, so i dont need to create / call a mixin for the rotate to generate the cross browser css within the .transform then?

Comment: Nope, the prefixes are all covered in the transform property. Rotate is not its own property. You can also check out http://shouldiprefix.com/ for which prefixes are required. I think only webkit and ms are actually required.

Comment: Yea just noticed from generated source :) almost had it then lol thanks for the helping hand mate.